# Differences between the N64 Passport Plus versions

Tags: hardware, nintendo-64

Last night I bought an N64 Passport Plus from someone on eBay, as there's a bigger range on N64 games, and some that I just can't find in Australia.

While researching the Passport, I noticed that there are four revisions - N64 Passport, N64 Passport Plus, and N64 Passport Plus II and III.

Are there any differences in versions, asides from what [wikipedia lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N64_Passport) in terms of game compatibility, and the original Passport not having Gameshark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this on Gamefaqs

> Unlike earlier convertors and previous versions of the Passport, this version will play every game on the N64 from every region with no side-effects such as bordering or 'ghosting' (a second 'ghost' image appearing on-screen giving a blurred effect).

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/n64/916387-nintendo-64/faqs/11366)

So it seems it's only a matter of tweaking and optimisation, comfort for the user. Just like when one is making an emulator, there are always some unnatended cases that makes you build a better product.